# ASP.NET Request.Cookies["cookie"] returns blank in IE on initial request

Tags: asp.net, cookies

We use openSSO to do the authentication of our website.
When a user is authenticated, openSSO redirects to what ever url was requested initially.
This is of course standard.
What is unusual is that in IE, when user is redirected, calling Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value is blank in IE but it works in Firefox, 
Request.Cookies["cookie"] is being added by the openSSO of course.

I have checked fiddler, firebug cookies the cookie is definitely being set (hence it works in FF)
The only way I can get this to work in IE is if after the initial redirect from opensso, i actually refresh the page using F5, then everything works as expected.

What is even more unusual is that on the initial redirect after authentication, the cookie is blank.. but putting "javascript:alert(document.cookie);" in the url bar shows that even in IE, the cookie values are there, just Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value thinks its blank (note that it is NOT null, only value is blank)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I have also see. The cookie is not actual set on page after the redirect. Happens because probably of bad synchronization of the browser.

One work around that I am doing is that I use a middle redirect page, so the browser have the time to save the cookie and the next page gets it.

For example what I do is this sequence. **LoginPage -> middleHiddenCheckPage -> FinalRedirectedPage.**